# conversion failed when converting the varchar value '19500.00' to data type int

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am still a novice to sql and would like some help please
trying to run this query

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
   SET SALARY = SALARY+3500
   WHERE SALARY < 33500;
```

On the below table

```
FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME        TITLE      AGE  SALARY
JONIE       WEBER-WILLIAMS  SECRETERY   28  19500.00
```

keep getting "conversion failed when converting the varchar value '19500.00' to data type int"

any reason why I'm getting this?

Comment: what is the datatype of your column `SALARY`?

Comment: @Nivas looks like it's `varchar` based on the title/error.

Comment: @DigitalChris yes, and OP may need a `CONVERT`

Comment: Fix the data structure so numbers are stored using numeric types rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `cast` or `convert`:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
SET SALARY=cast(SALARY as decimal(10,2))+3500 
WHERE cast(SALARY as decimal(10,2)) < 33500
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eeb9f/1)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to perform math and numeric comparisons on a string. You can work around this with a series of casts/converts as sgeddes mentions, but ultimately you should fix your table to use proper data types. Storing numbers/dates as strings will lead to a lot of workarounds that hurt performance and add a lot of code overhead to simple queries. Store `salary` as `MONEY` or `DECIMAL` and your initial query will run without issue.